# How to achieve client server communication using GSOCKET

Tags: client-server, glib, gio

I want to use gio and glib to create client-server communication. However, I'm getting confused with GSocket. Can someone give some examples.
Also, how can GMainLoop be helpful in this?

Comment: This is a very broad question. What specifically are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `GSocket` directly, go for `GSocketService` and `GSocketClient` which abstract the messy parts quite nicely.